# What is needed to remove my CPL restriction after becoming a US citizen?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification, cpl

I hold a US commercial pilot certificate based on my foreign commercial pilot certificate. This was allowed prior to the ruling that foreign pilots would only be issued a private certificate. On the back of my certificate there is a statement, "Not valid for the carriage of persons or property for compensation or hire or for agricultural aircraft operations".

I am now a US Citizen and I am wondering what I need to do to have this restriction removed.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think this has anything (directly) to do with citizenship. It's just about removing the restriction.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to pass the US commercial pilot test to remove the restriction.  If you have enough hours, you may want to consider applying for an ATP certificate.

A couple of things are required to be completed.

- Verify the authenticity of your foreign license through the FAA
  https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/airmen_certification/foreign_license_verification/
- Complete an application for the new commercial or ATP license
- Pass the appropriate practical test